# Installing ADT plugin 16.0.1 on Eclipse Indigo- windows

Tags: windows-7, adt, eclipse-indigo

When I try to install the ADT 16.0.1 plugin on Eclipse Indigo java developer edition release 1 or Helios normal edition release 2, I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138460759(SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138460759)
Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138460759 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138460759) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be found
```

I've tried to lookup the package it's refering to on apache, JDK reference and android developer reference but no luck!
This's not my first time installing ADT, I already have it installed on Ubuntu and it works. I also had the old release (ADT 15) installed on Eclipse galileo on windows, but I re-installed windows (i'm running windows 7 ultimate by the way) and I can run the old release but it's very good developing with ICS API-s.
So, if anyone could help, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am also having the same problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people have this type of problem with many different required items missing.
The last time I had this problem it was fixed by going to Window->Preferences
Then selecting Install/Update->Available Software Sites
Make sure everything listed is checked
In my installation I have:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7

You may also need to run Eclipse as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the ADT Plugin only after

- I moved the eclipse folder to a location without spaces (e.g.: c:\development\android\eclipse
- I ran the Eclipse Update procedure as administrator

Also I am using the 32bit version even though I use windows7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

run Eclipse with compatibility mode winXP pack 2 and Run as Administrator.
You can find it by Right clicking Eclipse.exe > Properties > Compatibility Tab